# Main differences between the types of CRM: SaaS CRM, Open-source CRM and Proprietary CR

Tags: crm

I am confused about the differences between SaaS CRM, open-source CRM, and Proprietary CRM. Here are a few of my confusions.

- Can proprietary CRM be SaaS CRM?
- Is SaaS CRM the way that the open-source CRM and Proprietary CRM is implemented/hosted or is it an entirely different type of CRM? If it is an entirely different type of CRM then what is the difference?
- Are SaaS and cloud hosting of proprietary CRM/Open-source the same thing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

- I don't think so. Maybe you pay for a few modules (like Sendgrid's sending email software or something)
- SaaS CRM is actually a proprietary CRM - but is not your company's property. You can develop your own proprietary CRM but usually don't worth it.
- Nope. A SaaS CRM will be a ready-to-use software with a lot of features build-in and hosted by the CRM owner (like Salesforce, HubSpot, and others). Open source CRM is a CRM maintained by some communities and is not for sell or at least you have the option to use it without paying - the drawback is lack of features ready-to-use, integrations and can take a time to finish the setup but at least is for free.

Answer (score 0):

SaaS CRM is a cloud-based CRM hosted and managed by third-party service providers, mostly on subscription models.

Whereas Open-Source CRM is a CRM system that allows anyone to view, modify and distribute its source code. It is mostly free but sometimes requires additional costs for further customization, maintenance, and support.

And when it's about Proprietary CRM, cloud-sourced software for handling business requirements, owned and managed by one vendor only. It is the most expensive option among the two mentioned above.

**Can proprietary CRM be SaaS CRM?**
Yes. Proprietary CRM can be SaaS CRM. Many vendors are already providing their proprietary CRM in the form of Cloud-based solutions and managing the hosting and users' access via web browsers. This way, proprietary CRM becomes affordable for businesses as everything related to maintenance, upgrades, and security is covered in the subscription fees for the software.

**Is SaaS CRM the way that the open-source CRM and Proprietary CRM are implemented/hosted or is it an entirely different type of CRM? If it is an entirely different type of CRM then what is the difference?**
The SaaS, open-source, and proprietary CRM models are different models of CRM implementation and hosting, not different kinds of CRM software.

SaaS CRM is hosted and managed by Third-party service providers. Open-source CRM entitles everyone to access, view, modify and distribute its source code over the internet. And Proprietary CRM is wholly owned and managed by a single vendor.

The major difference between these CRM models is their implementation and hosting methods. Depending on the needs, budget and degree of customization, businesses can choose SaaS, Open-Source or Proprietary CRM Solutions.

**Are SaaS and cloud hosting of proprietary CRM/Open-source the same thing?**
SaaS and Cloud Hosting of proprietary CRM or Open-source CRM are similar as they provide cloud-based delivery models where third-party hosts and manages the software. Although, they are not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Each type of CRM system caters to different requirements and enterprise needs. Here is a brief comparison:

1. SaaS CRM: This refers to 'Software as a Service'. SaaS CRM is generally most common. It offers a variety of benefits including cost-effectiveness, ease of access and minimal requirement for hardware infrastructure since everything is hosted in the cloud. SaaS CRM is a subscription-based model, often monthly or annually.
2. Open-source CRM: This type of CRM is highly customizable as it provides the source code. Users have the flexibility to modify functionalities as per their requirements. However, this requires an in-house IT team or paid developer. Open-source CRM is generally a cost-effective solution, especially for organizations with specific needs, but they can be a bit challenging to set up and maintain.
3. Proprietary CRM: This refers to a CRM system that is owned, controlled, and maintained by a single organization. It's highly secured and highly customizable. However, they usually involve higher set-up costs and maintenance, and require an in-house IT team.